# What is the difference between Einstein's and Boltzmann's definitions of probability?

Tags: mathematics, einstein, probability, statistical-mechanics, boltzmann

In the Einstein's 1905 paper on light quanta, he wrote the following about Boltzmann's notion of probability:

> The word probability is used in a sense that does not confirm to its definition as it given in the theory of probability. In particular "cases of equal probability" are often hypothetically defined in istances where the theoretical pictures used are sufficiently definite to give a deduction rather than a hypothetical assertion.

What does this mean?

Answer (score 1):

He's saying that the hypothesis of "cases of equal probability" is taken in situations ("instances") where the "theoretical picture" used is "definite" enough that we can deduce this hypothesis and not merely assert that this is the case.